# CSS geometrics - mixed shapes?

Tags: css, svg, canvas, geometry

is it possible to set the shape of an image not just with either straight or rounded shapes but with a mix of both?

I want my image in a emblem shape like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVT4H.jpg)
Is this possible just with css or do i need further svg/canvas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: such shape should be easy with SVG ... with CSS it will get complicated to achieve and maitain

Comment: it's possible, but would be too mush work to achieve it, but with `SVG` would be much easier. here [Check this Shapes of css](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) to get an idea.

Comment: so when i implement an image via img tag <img src="loremipsum" /> how i can affect the shape with an svg file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the css `clip-path` or `mask` properties with an svg. Here are some examples:

Clip Path:

```
.element-clip-path {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

Mask:

```
.element-mask {
    -webkit-mask: url(/path/to/mask.svg);
    -moz-mask: url(/path/to/mask.svg);
    -ms-mask: url(/path/to/mask.svg);
    -o-mask: url(/path/to/mask.svg);
    mask: url(/path/to/mask.svg);
}
```

Here is a great online tool you can use to create clip paths:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/